# How could I simplify this regular expression?

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression and need to see about cleaning it up/simplifying:

```
^\\\\server01\\c\$|ckpt|ect|fin_2\$/gim
```

I am trying to match multiple lines on the below:

Match any line that contains any variation of c$ (so `\\server01\c$\anything`)

OR

Match any line that contains `ckpt`, or `ect`, or `fin_2$`

There could be characters before or after any of these matches, such as `_ect`.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to make your question more clear. [*Quand t'es venue dans la rue inconnue...*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKqVx5DGViM)

Comment: Do you mean to require that you only match at the start of the line?

Comment: The start of the line will always be \\servername\. So I want to match that as the start, unless there is a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply just want to check if given line contains `c$`, `ckpt`, `ect`, or `fin_2$` you can simply use this Regex:

`^.*(?:c\$|ckpt|ect|fin_2\$).*$`

Explanation:

- `^` - anchors checking from the start of the line
- `.*` - matches any number of any characters (0 or more) UNTIL...
- `(?:  ... )` - is a non-capturing group. We do not want the match from this group to be extracted, but want to limit the OR'ing (`|`) to only inside the braces
- `c\$|ckpt|ect|fin_2\$` - match `c$` OR `ckpt` OR `ect` OR `fin_2$`. Note that literal `$` character needs to be escaped by `\`, as it has other use too (see below).
- `.*` - same as above, match any number of any characters UNTIL...
  `$` - the end of the line (or the end of the string if multiline flag is disabled)

Required flags to find all matches in a file containing multiple lines:

- `g` - global - doesn't return after first match (finds all matches)
- `m` - multiline - `$` applies to new-line characters as well as end of the string/file

Since your question doesn't include any programming language, my answer is limited to giving you a regex you can try out. However, all stuff related to setting flags (and/or escaping some characters) is on your side.

[Link to demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/LA9ewv/1)